# REGEX - Extracting a 9 digit value between 2 positive lookbehinds using Regex

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to extract the 9 digit number that appears between the lookbehind values (Form & FMLA). This is the logic I am using to target my lookbehinds: **(?<=Form)([\S\s]*)(?<=FMLA)**. Can I add another part to extract the 9 digit number? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Form** ( For Medical Leaves of Absence ) DO NOT return this document with your original request for a leave of absence .
Please email or fax this document to the HR Service Center 5 - 7 days before the date you're expected to return to work .

SECTION I : To be completed by Associate Associate's Name : Associate's Job Title : Associate ID ; Location / Store # James Doe Garden Associate 123456789 SECTION II : To be completed by a health care provider treating the associate / patient : Your patient is currently on leave of absence .
Answer , fully and completely , all applicable parts .
Several questions seek a response as to the frequency or duration of a condition , treatment , etc.
Your answer should be your best estimate based upon your medical knowledge 1 , experience , and examination of the patient .
Be as specific as you can ; terms such as "" lifetime , "" or "" indeterminate "" may not be sufficient to determine **FMLA** coverage .

Comment: Like `(?s)Form.*?\K\d{9}(?=.*?FMLA)`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/klt9Xm/1).

Comment: The .NET framework does not support \K, so when I enter this in regex, it errors out. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?s)(?<=Form.*?)\d{9}(?=.*?FMLA)
```

If you need to make sure there are no other digits enclosing the nine-digit substring, use

```cs
(?s)(?<=Form.*?)(?<!\d)\d{9}(?!\d)(?=.*?FMLA)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%28%3F%3C%3DForm.*%3F%29%5Cd%7B9%7D%28%3F%3D.*%3FFMLA%29&i=Form%20%28%20For%20Medical%20Leaves%20of%20Absence%20%29%20text...%0D%0A%0D%0ASECTION%20I%20%3A%20To%20be%20completed%20by%20Associate%20Associate%27s%20Name%20%3A%20Associate%27s%20Job%20Title%20%3A%20Associate%20ID%20%3B%20Location%20%2F%20Store%20%23%20James%20Doe%20Garden%20Associate%20123456789%20SECTION%20II%20%3A%20....%20Your%20answer%20should%20be%20your%20best%20estimate%20based%20upon%20your%20medical%20knowledge%201%20%2C%20experience%20%2C%20and%20examination%20of%20the%20patient%20.%20Be%20as%20specific%20as%20you%20can%20%3B%20terms%20such%20as%20%22%22%20lifetime%20%2C%20%22%22%20or%20%22%22%20indeterminate%20%22%22%20may%20not%20be%20sufficient%20to%20determine%20FMLA%20coverage%20.). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - a `RegexOptions.Singleline` inline modifier flag that makes `.` match across line boundaries
- `(?<=Form.*?)` - a positive lookbehind that requires `From` and then any zero or more chars, as few as possible, immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d{9}` - nine digits
- `(?=.*?FMLA)` - a positive lookahead that requires any zero or more chars, as few as possible, and then `FMLA` substring.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly!!! Also, since my team is on .NET framework, I will start using the .NET Regex Storm. The other Regex testing tool did not bring back a match when using this logic.

Comment: @KelvinLester You may use any regex testers to build the patterns, but you will need to test the validity at the .NET compatible regex tester. regexhero.net/tester/ is also a good tool.

Comment: Awesome and Thanks for sharing!!!

Answer (score -1):

You can add this construction to your regex to match 9 consecutive digits:

```
([0-9]{9})
```

`0-9` mean any digit between 0 and 9
`9` in curly brackets mean repeat the previous 9 times

The final regex expression should be:

```
(?<=Form)([\S\s]*)([0-9]{9})(?<=FMLA)
```

Comment: Where should I add it? I tried placing it at the end, and in the middle but it does not work. Do I need to omit something before adding? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @KelvinLester See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not work. I am getting the following error: Your regular expression does not match the subject string. The 9 digit number in my test data is not found. Have you tried using the logic you provided in a regex test string?

Comment: @KelvinLester, I am not developer and do not have .NET environment. And do not know how to test it (in .NET)

Comment: No problem and I appreciate you responding.